# Side menu overlap on main view ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

> In my ios app, i need side menu requirement, When click on menu
>   button, the sidebar slides above the main layer like below picture.
>   Can any one suggest me how to create a side menu like.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many third-party classes are available like:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/frostedsidebar
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kydrawercontroller
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/refrostedviewcontroller
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mvysidemenu
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cckfnavdrawer
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/btsimplesidemenu
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rnfrostedmenu
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cdrtranslucentsidebar
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/osblurslidemenu

Last one is very similar to your requirements....